# Angular2 & TypeScript importing of node_modules

Tags: import, typescript, angular

I had a very simple 'hello world' Angular2 app. I also made the apparently unreasonable decision to work with different directory structures between my dev project and the final deployment folder on my spring backend.

Because of this difference, I had an issue with the TypeScript imports, and this line ended up producing 404 errors (unable to find /angular2/core library) when I tried to open the actual app in my browser:

```
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/core';
```

So long story short, I ended up adding back the /app folder to make everything work, but I ended up modifying my import statements as follows:

```
import {Component, View} from '../node_modules/angular2/core';
```

This, however, turned out to cause some weird behavior. For some reason specifying `../node_modules` in the library paths is causing the JS to actually load ALL Angular2 files from scratch using ajax calls to retrieve each and every individual file from the `npm_modules/angular2/` folder even though this was part of my HTML header:

```
<script src="/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
```

When I finally realized what's going on I reverted the import statement back to

```
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/core';
```

and it all worked. Angular2 was now completely loaded from the script tag above and there were no files getting loaded by extra ajax calls.

Can someone please explain what is causing this? I assume it's normal behavior but I don't understand how the importing works and why specifying a more detailed path makes such a difference.

Comment: For more detail on importing modules in a TS world: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html

The docs are done well for this. Really.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The `import` rules of TypeScript follow the same convention as node.js. If an import begins with a dot:

```
import {Something} from './some/path';
```

Then it is treated as a relative path from the file that declares the import. If however it is an absolute path:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
```

Then it is assumed to be an external module, so Typescript will walk up the tree looking for a `package.json` file, then go into the `node_modules` folder, and find a folder with the same name as the import, then looks in the `package.json` of the module for the main `.d.ts` or `.ts` file, and then loads that, *or* will look for a file that has the same name as the one specified, *or* an `index.d.ts` or `index.ts` file.

Wow that seems complex when written out, and there are still some exceptions there... But all in all, if you have worked with node.js before then this should behave exactly the same way.

One thing to note is that there is a TypeScript compiler option that should be set for typing resolutions to work in this way

*in tsconfig.json*

```
"moduleResolution": "node"
```

Now the second part of your question was how does this get loaded without using ajax calls. This is a feature of `System.js`. The script tag that is loaded in the `index.html` file imports a bundle which registers the angular2 bundle with System. Once this has happened System knows about these files and correctly assigns them to their references. It's a pretty deep topic but a lot of information can be found either in the README of [systemjs](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs), or [systemjs-builder](https://github.com/systemjs/builder).

Comment: Thanks heaps for the detailed and well written answer. I've been using nodejs at work for a few years now but I've somehow managed to avoid running into this problem until now. Glad I now know what's going on behind the scenes - thanks again!

Comment: @Thierry Templier: hi, I have code use node.js modules, for example, `var fs: any = require('fs')`. It cause the problem. Do you know how can I use import to do this?

Comment: @Ng2-Fun The 'fs' is a node core module that will not be available in the browser so Systemjs will not be able to locate the file to load. This is an issue I am having for a different use case. Even if running in node, Systemjs will attempt to load a module for this, even though it doesn't need to. I am yet to find a solution for this other than to compile the typescript to commonjs instead (though I haven't tried running the application in this way). For non-angular2 typescript in node using commonjs you can use `import * as fs from 'fs';` which should give you what you need.

Comment: @SnareChops: I actually tried compiling the typescript to commonjs in my angular2 app, it still doesn't work either.

Comment: If I do an 'npm install some-lib' and then in one of the ts files use 'import * as sl from 'some-lib', I assume that systemjs loads this. When I build/serve, the sources includes the nodes/modules/some-lib folder - but what creates this folder? It's working - tried it in Angular 2 Quickstart - but I can't figure out what creates and populates node-modules folder when I do a build/serve!

Comment: Hi, I have tried the things you mentioned above in my typescript application, but I am getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined" error when browser loads the .js file (compiled by TSC). Please suggest.

Comment: @Shivam You need to load the compiled result using a module loader of your choice. Popular ones are Browserify, Webpack, SystemJS, RequireJS, etc. Pick your poison and ensure you target the right output. Welcome to the most difficult part of developing for the browser.