# How does Angular2 resolve imports?

Tags: typescript, angular

So, I am learning Angular2, and I am using TypeScript. So, I do know that SystemJS is used to get the `import` functionality like this:

`import { bootstrap } from "angular2/platform/browser";`

This makes sense, but, I don't understand where exactly `angular2/platform/browser` is. I am pretty sure it is not a path, but some other thing that is used to simulate paths/namespaces. Also, looking at `bootstrap` here, is it a class? Or is it just a function. And is it possible for other stuff to be imported?

Any exceptional answers will receive a bounty from me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In fact, there are several things to understand here:

- TypeScript files are transpiled into JavaScript files. When configuring your TypeScript compiler, you will configure how the `import` will be translate in your `tsconfig.json` file. This configuration tells to use SystemJS:

  ```
  {
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "ES5",
      "module": "system",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "removeComments": false,
      "noImplicitAny": false
    },
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules"
    ]
  }
  ```
- This way the transpiled TypeScript file will look like the following:

  ```
  System.register(['angular2/platform/browser', 'angular2/router', 'angular2/http', 'angular2/core', './app.component', './services/companies.service'], function(exports_1) {
    var browser_1, router_1, http_1, core_1, router_2, app_component_1, companies_service_1;
    return {
      (...)
    }
  });
  ```

  You can see that the imports are part of the parameters of the `System.register` function. It's the way SystemJS will provide you the elements you need from other modules. Corresponding list is based on the `import` you use in the TypeScript code... To have the list above, I used this code:

  ```
  import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
  import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router';
  import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
  import {provide} from 'angular2/core';
  import {LocationStrategy, Location, HashLocationStrategy } from 'angular2/router'; 
  import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
  import {CompanyService} from './services/companies.service';
  ```
- The `System.register` function accepts several parameters. In the previous case, the name of the module isn't defined only the import. It's because we use the following configuration of SystemJS in the HTML file. This tells that the name of the module corresponds to the file itself:

  ```
  <script>
    System.config({
      packages: {        
        app: {
          format: 'register',
          defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
      }
    });
    System.import('app/boot')
         .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
  </script>
  ```
- Regarding Angular2, the JS files contained in the `node_modules/angular2/bundles` (for example `http.dev.js`) contain several modules in files. In this case, there modules are registered into SystemJS using the `System.register` function but with an additional parameter:

  ```
  System.register("angular2/http", ["angular2/core", "angular2/src/http/http", "angular2/src/http/backends/xhr_backend", "angular2/src/http/backends/jsonp_backend", "angular2/src/http/backends/browser_xhr", "angular2/src/http/backends/browser_jsonp", "angular2/src/http/base_request_options", "angular2/src/http/base_response_options", "angular2/src/http/static_request", "angular2/src/http/static_response", "angular2/src/http/interfaces", "angular2/src/http/backends/browser_xhr", "angular2/src/http/base_request_options", "angular2/src/http/base_response_options", "angular2/src/http/backends/xhr_backend", "angular2/src/http/backends/jsonp_backend", "angular2/src/http/http", "angular2/src/http/headers", "angular2/src/http/enums", "angular2/src/http/url_search_params"], true, function(require, exports, module) {
    var global = System.global,
    __define = global.define;
    global.define = undefined;
    (...)
  });
  ```

To summarize, this is based on a module system like SystemJS that is responsible of module resolution.

SnareChops posted a great answer regarding this in this question:

- [Angular2 & TypeScript importing of node_modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35159872/angular2-typescript-importing-of-node-modules)

Comment: Thanks for the shout out. Also I've created a chat room for Angular2 [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102765/angular2) for anyone that would like to discuss anything related.