# My angular 2 app takes a long time to load for first time users, I need help to speed it up

Tags: typescript, angular

Below I have pasted in my app.ts file.

I'm using angular2, with firebase and typescript.

Is the reason its slow because I have a lot of routes and I'm injecting a lot of files?

Also, my app works fine its just for first time users visiting the homepage I have this issue for.

I'm not sure if the bootstrap can be improved at the bottom or if I'm doing anything wrong.

**This is my app.ts file:**

```
import {Component, bind, provide, Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser'
import {NgIf} from 'angular2/common';
import {Router, Location, ROUTER_BINDINGS, RouterOutlet, RouteConfig, RouterLink, ROUTER_PROVIDERS, APP_BASE_HREF, CanActivate, OnActivate,
    ComponentInstruction} from 'angular2/router';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http, Headers} from 'angular2/http';
import {ANGULAR2_GOOGLE_MAPS_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2-google-maps/core';
import {enableProdMode} from 'angular2/core';
enableProdMode();

import {LoggedInRouterOutlet} from './interceptor';

import {AuthService} from './services/authService/authService';
import {SocialService} from './services/socialService/socialService';
import {UserService} from './services/userService/userService';
import {OrganisationService} from './services/organisationService/organisationService';
import {NotificationService} from './services/notificationService/notificationService';
import {EmailService} from './services/emailService/emailService';

import {UserProfile} from './models/profile/profile';
import {Organisation} from './models/organisation/organisation';

import {HeaderNavigation} from './components/header/header';
import {HeaderNavigationLoggedIn} from './components/header/headerNavigationLoggedIn';
import {HeaderNavigationLoggedInCompany} from './components/header/headerNavigationLoggedInCompany';
import {Footer} from './components/footer/footer';
import {SideMenuCompany} from './components/header/sideMenuCompany';
import {SideMenuUser} from './components/header/sideMenuUser';
import {Splash} from './components/splash/splash';

import {CreateJob} from './components/createJob/createJob';
import {SearchJobs} from './components/searchJobs/searchJobs';
import {Login} from './components/login/login';
import {Applications} from './components/applications/applications';
import {Register} from './components/register/register';
import {ForgotPassword} from './components/forgotpassword/forgotpassword';
import {ChangePassword} from './components/changepassword/changepassword';
import {ChangeEmail} from './components/changeemail/changeemail';
import {SocialRegister} from './components/socialregister/socialregister';
import {Admin} from './components/admin/admin';
import {Contact} from './components/contact/contact';
import {SearchUsers} from './components/searchusers/searchusers';

import {Jobs} from './components/job/jobs';
import {CompanyProfile} from './components/company/company';
import {Home} from './components/home/home';
import {Dashboard} from './components/dashboard/dashboard';
import {Profile} from './components/profile/profile';
import {UserApplications} from './components/userApplications/userApplications';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    providers: [UserService, UserProfile, OrganisationService, Organisation],
    template: `

        <Splash *ngIf="isLoggedIn"></Splash>    

        <HeaderNavigation *ngIf="!isLoggedIn"></HeaderNavigation>       

        <HeaderNavigationLoggedIn *ngIf="isLoggedIn && isUserLogin"></HeaderNavigationLoggedIn>
        <HeaderNavigationLoggedInCompany *ngIf="isLoggedIn && isCompanyLogin"></HeaderNavigationLoggedInCompany>

        <SideMenuCompany *ngIf="isLoggedIn && isCompanyLogin"></SideMenuCompany>
        <SideMenuUser *ngIf="isLoggedIn && isUserLogin"></SideMenuUser>

        <div class="content">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet> 
        </div>     
    `,
    directives: [RouterOutlet, RouterLink, Splash, HeaderNavigation, HeaderNavigationLoggedIn, NgIf, HeaderNavigationLoggedInCompany, SideMenuCompany, SideMenuUser, Footer, LoggedInRouterOutlet]
})

@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/', component: Home, as: 'Home', data:{title: 'Welcome Home'}},
    { path: '/home', component: Home, as: 'Home', useAsDefault: true},
    { path: '/login', component: Login, as: 'Login' },  
    { path: '/register/:id', component: Register, as: 'Register' },
    { path: '/forgotpassword', component: ForgotPassword, as: 'ForgotPassword' },
    { path: '/dashboard', component: Dashboard, as: 'Dashboard' },
    { path: '/search', component: SearchJobs, as: 'Search' },   
    { path: '/profile', component: Profile, as: 'Profile' },
    { path: '/settings', component: CompanyProfile, as: 'Settings' },
    { path: '/jobs', component: Jobs, as: 'Jobs' },
    { path: '/password', component: ChangePassword, as: 'Password' },
    { path: '/email', component: ChangeEmail, as: 'Email' },
    { path: '/applications', component: Applications, as: 'Applications' },
    { path: '/socialRegister/:id', component: SocialRegister, as: 'SocialRegister' },
    { path: '/socialRegister', component: SocialRegister, as: 'SocialRegister' },
    { path: '/applys', component: UserApplications, as: 'Applys' },
    { path: '/contact', component: Contact, as: 'Contact' },
    { path: '/searchTeachers', component: SearchUsers, as: 'SearchUsers' },
    { path: '/createJob', component: CreateJob, as: 'CreateJob' },
    { path: '/adminmarkchris2016', component: Admin, as: 'AdminMarkChris2016' },

    { path:'/**', redirectTo: ['Home']}
])

@Injectable()

export class AppComponent {
    router: Router;
    location: Location;
    authService: AuthService;
    userService: UserService
    isLoggedIn: boolean = false;
    isCompanyLogin: boolean = false;
    isUserLogin: boolean = false;
    userProfile: UserProfile;   

    constructor(_router: Router, _location: Location, _authService: AuthService, _userService: UserService, _userProfile: UserProfile){ 
        this.router = _router;
        this.location = _location;
        this.authService = _authService;
        this.userService = _userService;
        this.userProfile = _userProfile;

        this.isUserLoggedIn(this.location.path());

        //On refresh
        this.router.subscribe((currentRoute) => {
            this.isUserLoggedIn(currentRoute);
        })  
    }

    isUserLoggedIn(currentRoute): void{ 
        this.authService.checkIfLoggedIn().then((response) => { 
            this.isLoggedIn = response

            if(this.isLoggedIn){
                this.isUserOrganisationOrTeacher();                 
            }   

            if(currentRoute.substring(0, 14) == "socialRegister" || currentRoute == "socialRegister" || currentRoute == "home" || currentRoute == "contact" || currentRoute == "" || currentRoute == "forgotpassword" || currentRoute == "login" || currentRoute.substring(0, 8) == "register"){
                this.isCompanyLogin = false;
                this.isUserLogin = false;
                this.isLoggedIn = false;
            }           
        });  
    }

    isUserOrganisationOrTeacher(): void{
        this.userService.checkIfProfileExists().then((response) => {
            this.isCompanyLogin = false;
            this.isUserLogin = false;       

            if(response){
                this.isUserLogin = true;
                this.isCompanyLogin = false;
            }else{
                this.isCompanyLogin = true; 
                this.isUserLogin = false;                   
            }
        }); 
    }       
}

bootstrap(AppComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS, provide(APP_BASE_HREF, {useValue: '/'}), HTTP_PROVIDERS, AuthService, SocialService, UserService, EmailService, OrganisationService, NotificationService, ANGULAR2_GOOGLE_MAPS_PROVIDERS]);
```

Comment: What is the size of your application?

Comment: Of the whole app file?

Comment: 6.9megabytes for the whole app

Comment: 6.9M?! Consider pre-rendering. I'm not even sure how 6.9M of JS is possible. This is minified?!

Comment: @DaveNewton It's called Angular2. That beast is huge.

Comment: I've used it, but not to the tune of 6.9M of JS. But apparently it's not just the JS, which is good at least. A mid-sized test app I created was on the order of 4M, before minification, much smaller after.

Comment: Probably you are building images (base64?), templates?
Consider using a serverside rendering and lazy loading for your components.

6.9MB are too many, your app cannot land in production!

Comment: I've got it down to 2.5mb

Comment: I removed some images i wasnt using

Comment: I've now got it down to 18.mg, whats a good size for an angular 2 app?

Comment: Some pointers https://stackoverflow.com/a/63279047/5043867

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To have something ready for production (and speed it up), you need to package it.

I mean transpiling all files into JavaScript ones and concat them the same way Angular2 does for example. This way you will have several modules contained into a single JS file. This way you will reduce the number of HTTP calls to load your application code into the browser.

As a matter of fact, for the following configuration of SystemJS, you will have one call per module (it's suitable for development but not really efficient in production):

```html
    <script>
      System.config({
        packages: {        
          app: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          }
        }
      });
      System.import('app/boot')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
```

This answer could give hints about how module resolution works:

- [How does Angular2 resolve imports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35253719/how-does-angular2-resolve-imports/35253891#35253891)

You can do this packaging using Gulp and its plugins:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-tsc
- https://github.com/contra/gulp-concat

See the following answers:

- [Using Gulp to Concatenate and Uglify files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24591854/using-gulp-to-concatenate-and-uglify-files)
- https://github.com/JavascriptMick/angular2-gulp-typescript/blob/master/gulpfile.js

Comment: I have put my website live but all my js and ts files are visible when I view the source in the console on chrome. How can I use gulp to hide those? I could do this in angular 1, but not sure how in angular 2

Comment: I made a new question related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35361394/how-do-i-uglify-my-angularjs-2-typescript-app-files-and-wire-up-for-a-production

Comment: I tried something similar to this on my project here https://github.com/jrgleason/ng2-webpack-demo but I still see some  performance issues. Is this just as fast as it can go?

Comment: I have just followed the angular 2 quickstart. The quickstart does the same thing as your answer - config and import.. but it still doesnt create a single JS file

Answer (score 7):

Though late, for people comming here now...if you are using angular2+ then try

```
ng build --prod --env=<staging or prod or your env file>
```

It will do AoT, bundling cache busting and minification all in one command.
More deatils can be found in Angular official website in [`ng build` section](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build#bundling--tree-shaking). In my case one of the `chunk` was actually 2.4MB which was reduced to 450+KB but after including `--prod` it was further reduced to 200+KB

Good size for an app depends. Angular2 has the concept of **lazy loading** of code or **chunking**. You can split your app into chunks (like admin UI and user UI) and load them on demand so  that the entire app need not be loaded initially which will help in reduced load time. The following articles could be of extra help:

- https://blog.waffle.io/code-splitting-in-angular-2-with-webpack-2-ce8dd4b8b23e
- http://blog.rangle.io/optimize-your-angular2-application-with-tree-shaking/
- http://blog.mgechev.com/2016/06/26/tree-shaking-angular2-production-build-rollup-javascript/

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this same problem, basically you just need to run the webpack build in production mode.

To do this install webpack globaly `npm install webpack -g` Once installed, run `webpack -p` from your apps root directory. This brought my file size down from over 5MB to about 700KB

Comment: Hi, I've installed webpack globally and then I ran webpack -p and nothing happenend. When you say apps root directory, do you mean app? src? where exactly

Comment: @David Herod Can you explain in details/ webpack doesn't work

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is most probably related to file size delivered to client. 6.9MB is huge both in terms of network and parsing/evaluation time.

Suggestions:

1. Minify your application
2. Split it into multiple bundles (vendors.js, core.js, ...)

Answer (score 1):

Another possibly approach to speed up your app is to use [Lazy Loading](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules)

That way, your appModule will reduce the imports and the modules will be called on demand.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is zone.js on polyfills, Zone.js slowdown the app considerable