# how can I minimize&packaging Angular2 without Node.JS?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angular, webpack

### Reason:

I am doing one POC SPA with Angular2(using RC version).
Limited by company policy, we cannot install Node.JS, so Webpack is not available to me.
By now, there are 800+ HTTP requests(total 2.5 MB) at least once I load App home. Because we have developed many components among the App.

### Question:

May you please advise me on How I can do minimize&packaging Angular2 code without Node.JS? (something like Third Party Library, Eclipse plugin and so on)
In other words, I want the Front-end one key deployment would be involved.

I think it would obviously increase performance.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you're going to struggle finding an equivalent tool that's doesn't use Node, unfortunately. The other big names when it comes to module bundling are Browserify, SystemJS and Rollup, and they all require Node too.

Comment: yes. it is not make sense if no Node.JS. But hope If there is a miracle.

Comment: If you can use gulp, take a look at MrCroft's answer (highest rated) about using `SystemJS Builder` at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35280582/angular2-too-many-file-requests-on-load . That's what I did to take my app from 450 requests on first load down to just 3 JS and a few CSS/HTML requests.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer, I'm the author of [Angular2 Eclipse](https://github.com/angelozerr/angular2-eclipse/wiki/Getting-Started).

I suggest you that you try [Angular2 Eclipse](https://github.com/angelozerr/angular2-eclipse/wiki/Getting-Started) which is based on [TypeScript IDE](https://github.com/angelozerr/typescript.java/wiki/Getting-Started).

When you install TypeScript IDE, you can [install an embed node.js](https://github.com/angelozerr/typescript.java/wiki/Configuration#configure-nodejs), so without installing at hand the node.js, you will benefit with TypeScript completion, validation, compilation, etc (which requires node.js to consume TypeScript tsserver).

You can even choose your [version of TypeScript](https://github.com/angelozerr/typescript.java/wiki/Configuration#configure-typescript)

Angular2 Eclipse provide the [Angular CLI integration](https://github.com/angelozerr/angular2-eclipse/wiki/AngularCLI) with terminal, wizards, launches, but in this case you need to install node.js (because it uses `ng` command that you must install it with `npm install -g angular-cli`

Please create [an issue](https://github.com/angelozerr/angular2-eclipse/issues) to give the capability to use `ng` command without installation:

- `ng` should use the embed node.js (to avoid installing node.js)
- provide an Eclipse Preference to link `ng` to a custom path (the custom path could be the angular-cli project that will download and host in your GIT, SVN repository).