# Angular 2 requests performance issue

Tags: angularjs, performance, angular, request, angular-cli

I'm using the Angluar CLI starter kit, And I'm having issues with the performance. It's impossible for me to work on my app with Firefox, so I have to work with Chrome (which eats lots of RAM). I was looking on the network traffic console of my chrome, and I saw these details:

```
387 request | 143 KB transferred | Finish: 5.38 s | DOMContentLoader: 575 ms | Load: 1.34s
```

This is so sick, I'm not surprised that my Firefox can't barely handle it. And I barely started to develop my App.

So, my questions are:

- Is it normal?
- Will it be like that when I'll set my app to production?
- Is there any solution for this?

---

This is not a possible dublicate of [Angular2 too many file requests on load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35280582) because I'm using [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) And it's much more different, I don't know even how can I combine Webpack with this framework.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 too many file requests on load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35280582/angular2-too-many-file-requests-on-load)

Answer (score 1):

This is the reason for 387 requests, in `systemjs.config.js`:

```
 // Individual files (~300 requests):
  function packIndex(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }
  // Bundled (~40 requests):
  function packUmd(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: '/bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }
  // Most environments should use UMD; some (Karma) need the individual index files
  var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;
  // Add package entries for angular packages
```

So you could reduce that to 40 requests if you set `System.packageWithIndex = false`:

```
   <script>
         System.packageWithIndex = false;
        System.import('./app/bootstrap').catch(console.log.bind(console));
    </script>
```

Comment: There's no such file `systemjs.config.js` in Angular CLI's starter kit.

Comment: It's in the index.html file, sorry

Comment: Well, do you know how can I reduce the number of the requests on `angular-cli`?