# Best way to bundle Angular2 4.1.2 project regarding loading time

Tags: javascript, angular, web

I am relatively new to Angular 2. After almost finishing and uploading my project (still in production mode) for testing I realized that it's loading very slow. It takes 10-20 seconds until the view is shown.
Inspecting the network tab in chrome developer tools shows:

- 8.7 MB transferred (this seems a lot. normal?)
- 408 requests (mostly js files including node_modules and components which 
  are loaded seperately)

So I'm basically wondering:

- how can my application be so incredibly slow? (tried not to implement 
  unnecessary plugins etc.)
- what can I do to improve performance?
- what is the best way to bundle the js files (preferably using grunt)

I don't use webpack.
I Have Grunt as a task runner.
The site is hosted on a vserver.

Url to the application:
http://test.philipdrozd.com

Comment: drop away systemjs and use webpack. Explained here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35280582/angular2-too-many-file-requests-on-load

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 too many file requests on load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35280582/angular2-too-many-file-requests-on-load)