# My Angular 2 app load very slowly for the first time

Tags: angular

[image]

Why is my Angular app loading so slow for the first time?
What is causing the **compiler.umd.js** to take almost 5 seconds to load before other files are allowed to load?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My angular 2 app takes a long time to load for first time users, I need help to speed it up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35253914/my-angular-2-app-takes-a-long-time-to-load-for-first-time-users-i-need-help-to)

Comment: points might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/63279047/5043867

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not using any bundle tools like webpack, systemjs..

When you deploy your ng2-app, I should use AOT(ahead of time) compile.
I guess you are using JIT(just in time) compile.

In angular2 guide page,

> With AOT, the browser downloads a pre-compiled version of the application. The browser loads executable code so it can render the application immediately, without waiting to compile the app first.

When you use JIT compile, your browser will download vendor.js which is defined angular2 compiler and it will compile your app just in time. It will be too slow.

I recommend to use AOT compile when you deploy, and use lazy loading for resource size.

If you are curious about ng2 AOT compile, read this guide.

[angualar2-cookbook-AOT](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html)

And here is example angular2 app with webpack2 and lazy load.

files bundled with aot is smaller than 500KB.

[angular2-webpack2-aot](https://github.com/tk5641/angular2-webpack2-aot)