# Exception in main.ts when importing components via an index.ts file

Tags: typescript, angular

I know that this exception:

> Unexpected directive value '**undefined**' on the View of component '**AppComponent**'

is quite common, but no other question helped me, since they often refer to circular dependencies or missing `export` statements. But no fix fits to this problem...

I have a project with the following structure

```
src/
    myproject/
        components/
        services/
        templates/
        ...
        main.ts
    index.html
    systemjs.config.js
public/
    libs/                   <- required libs, copied from node_modules
    myproject/              <- compiled .ts files and copied resources from /src/myproject
    index.html              <- copied from /src/myproject
    systemjs.config.js      <- copied from /src/myproject
gulpfile.ts
*.json                      <- tsconfig, package, typings, ...
```

The process to deploy the project is the following: compile `.ts` files, output them to `/public`. Copy all resources (everything but `.ts` files) to `/public`. Copy all required libs to `/public/libs`.

I am using typescript `1.9`, since I am using the `paths` option in `tsconfig.json`. This file contains the following path mapping:

```
// excerpt from /tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        // more options
        "paths": {
            "myproject/*": ["./src/myproject/*"]
        }
        // more options
    }
}
```

All my Angular2 components are in the folder `/src/myproject/components` and there is an `index.ts` file which exports every defined class. This file looks like this:

```
// /src/myproject/components/index.ts
export * from './app.component';
export * from './a.component';
export * from './b.component';
export * from './c.component';
```

The reason for this setup is to be able to have good looking and easy imports. For example, if I need `ComponentA`, `ComponentB` and `ComponentC` (which are defined in `/src/myproject/components/{a,b,c}.component.ts`), then I can just make the following statement:

```
// excerpt from /src/myproject/components/app.component.ts
import  { ComponentA, ComponentB, ComponentC } from 'myproject/components';
```

This does work very well: I have no issues when compiling, and no issues when accessing it in the browser (`systemjs.config.js` takes care of the proper resolution)

But there is one exception. If I import the main `AppComponent` (`/src/myproject/components/app.component.ts`) in the `main.ts` file (`/src/myproject/main.ts`) like this:

```
// excerpt from /src/myproject/main.ts
import { AppComponent } from 'myproject/components';
```

I get the following exception when trying to view myproject in the browser:

> **EXCEPTION**: Unexpected directive value '**undefined**' on the View of component '**AppComponent**'

However, if I change this import to the following:

```
// excerpt from /src/myproject/main.ts
import { AppComponent } from 'myproject/components/app.component';
```

Everything works as expected. Please note, that the `main.ts` is the only file where this import does not work. All other imports work like a charm. For example, in `AppComponent`, like you can see above.

If I would write everything down, this question would be way to large, so please excuse me that I decided to only add a MWE as a GitHub repository. You can get the whole code from:

https://github.com/christiandreher/ang-exc-mwe

I also pushed the `/public` directory. Accessing this with a browser, you should technically get the same error. If you want to build it yourself, you can use `gulp clean`, `tsc` (note: `gulp build` does not work due to a bug in `gulp-typescript`), `gulp resources`, `gulp libs`.

**So the question is: Why does every import work, except for the first one in `main.ts`?** I really like this setup, since I can import everything very conveniently and it just looks good. **Also, I want it consistently**.

I really appreciate any help, since this is a huge question, and to be honest, a *not so* minimal working example...

**Update**: So far I have only received answers on how to fix the exception, but I have supplied a fix for this by myself in the OP. I know how to avoid it, but **I don't want to use relative imports**, I want it constistently everywhere. So **what can I do to fix this one exception? What is the cause of this? If it is not fixable: Why? Who do I have to address for this issue? TypeScript, Angular, ...?**

**Update 2**: As I still didn't manage to get this to work, I will now start a bounty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `export * from './app.component';` at the end of the `index.ts`

```ts
// /src/myproject/components/index.ts
export * from './a.component';
export * from './b.component';
export * from './c.component';
export * from './app.component';
```

I suppose it should work, since I had the same problem.

---

If it doesn't, do the below:

- Think of `index.ts` as having all the code of exported files written in it.
- And then reorder the exports according to **define first use later** rule
- Don't use `index.ts` as proxy for the files that are exported in it, and uses some other file that is also exported from the same `index.ts` file, and vice-versa (aka: **circular-dependency**). In other words
- Wherever you can do `./some-component` to import, don't use `index.ts` there, which is necessary if you have `some-other-component` in the same `index.ts (read Directory)` importing each other from `index.ts`, this will fail.
- Same above applies to `services` as well.
- It should work by now, if doesn't, look at constructor of AppComponent and see if there are other `index.ts` exports in use, having internal dependencies with each other, then reorder them with same rule.
- This is the same reason why we don't define two classes in a single file.

Comment: Indeed putting the `app.component` at the bottom of the `index.ts` file solved the problem! I am so happy, thank you very much :) So it actually _was_ a circular dependency problem, right?

Comment: You're welcome....   me too, for obvious reasons ;) .....  hm, not actually, more of `used before declaration`, I think.

Comment: Hmm interessting... I think there is a lot of improvement potential regarding typescript. This shouldn't be an issue imho

Answer (score 0):

I would import like this:

```
// excerpt from /src/myproject/main.ts
import { AppComponent } from './components';
```

with the following SystemJS configuration:

```
System.config({
  (...)
  packages: {
    (...)
    src: {
      main: 'index.js',
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: The question is: why does it not work with `myproject/components`? There must be an error somewhere, because in all other files it does work. I would like to have it consistently

Answer (score 0):

### update

For me only relative paths work with me, when I import an absolute path not working correctly except those in `node_modules` I found an useful link can help you [Angular2 & TypeScript importing of node_modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35159872/angular2-typescript-importing-of-node-modules).

---

You need to change the import to

```
import { AppComponent } from './components';
```

It works fine for me

Comment: This doesn't answer my question, too. I would like to leave it as it is, with `myproject/components`, and fix the error why this one, single import is not working

Comment: For me only relative paths work with me, when I import an absolute path not working correctly except those in `node_modules` I found an useful link can help you [Angular2 & TypeScript importing of node_modules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35159872/angular2-typescript-importing-of-node-modules)

Comment: The repo referenced in the OP works with absolute paths. Well, except this single import in `main.ts`. Well, thanks for your effort :)