# Angular Full Stack, How to Use External Libraries?

Tags: angular, import, mean-stack

I am using Angular Full stack that uses Angular 2 and I just starting to learn it. It seems like the structures of pure Angular 2 vs the Full stack is quite different, so I am having some troubles following other guides such as [Angular2 & TypeScript importing of node_modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35159872/angular2-typescript-importing-of-node-modules)

My question is:
How do I use a node-module for my client side, that I have installed?

Here is what I have tried so far:

- The external library I would like to use is https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-star-rating (even though I've tried others)
- I do "npm install angular-star-rating"
- Here is where I am stuck. I've tried multiple things such as importing it in the component.ts I want to use it in, loading the scripts in the html, and loading the module in my app.ts. I don't see system.config (from system.js, though I believe it is used), nor any place with @NgModule where I can load in the module, so I thought the best suitable places was app.ts. I would get errors when I do "gulp serve", errors such as

  ERROR in ./~/angular-star-rating/src/star-rating.component.ts
  Module parse failed: [directory]  Unexpected character '@' (14:0)
  You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
  SyntaxError: Unexpected character '@' (14:0)
- Here is a quick look at my project structure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZT4m.jpg

Thanks, any help is appreciated greatly

Comment: Are you using any build tool, like angular CLI?

Comment: Yes, I'm using angular full stack generator (https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack)

Comment: Add --save in npm install command. This will add it as project dependency

Comment: The full stack generator is based on Angular1.6. Are you sure you are working on Angular1 or on Angular2

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
<div star-rating rating="starRating2" read-only="true" max-rating="7" click="click2(param)" mouse-hover="mouseHover2(param)" mouse-leave="mouseLeave2(param)"></div>
```

And you must specify inside of your scope too such as in above case you use `starRating2` as parameter. In this case you create scope and define value for this like in below:

```
app.controller('appController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.starRating2 = 5;
}])
```

Check this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/manishpatil/2fahpk7s/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm still unsure of how you would import the star-rating module from node though. I see the link doing that part, just html and controller

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Add as project dependency

```
npm install --save angular-star-rating
```

Step 2:
Add to index.html

```
<script src="[bower or npm folder]/angular-star-rating/dist/index.js"></script>
```

Step 3:
Import in Component

```
import { StarRatingModule } from 'path/to/star/rating/star-rating.module';
@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    ...
    StarRatingModule
    ...
  ]
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Step 4: Update HTML

```
<star-rating-comp
         [size]="'large'"
         [rating]="3"
         [text]="'Rating:'"
         (onRatingChange)="crtl.onRatingChange($event)">
 </star-rating-comp>
```

Comment: Hi Manmeet, thanks for your reply. 
I've tried your suggestion to do --save, but that still does not work. As for the original question, I am still unsure of where to add the <script> (pretty sure it would be in the route's html, ie my displaySite.html in this screenshot if that is where I want to use it http://imgur.com/0AnAKBU).
I have tried importing it again in app.ts as well as displaySite.component.ts but neither works, coming up with the same error pasted above.
As for Step 3, my Webstorm does not recognize @NgModule, nor is it used anywhere in my project?